# Can't access 'event' properties when calling it in Lambda Function in AWS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, rest, aws-api-gateway

I have a specific issue on my AWS lambda function that I have recently built (in python 3.8). It's supposed to support a post request and put an item from the body of the request into a table in DynamoDB.

My Lambda function looks like this:

[image]

When I test using API Gateway it works perfectly and I get what I expect.
 and the item gets inserted into the table. This is the response on the API-Gateway Test:

[image]

Here's my API gateway post method set up:

[image]

However, when I use postman and try to post a JSON I get this Key Error: (Note the JSON body of the post is identical).

[image]

Any help I get here will be very much appreciated.

Edit: For those who have read the comments below. This is the code I'm using to return the event:

[image]

Comment: print event on both and see the difference

Comment: add `print(json.dumps(event))` to your lambda and check in CW Logs the outcome.

Comment: In Postman, is Content-Type set to application/json? Is Content-Length calculated when request is sent? Is the body raw json?

Comment: @jarmod Yes to all of those

Comment: So I'm getting: 'Log group does not exist in this account or region.' when trying to access CW logs. The assigned role has a 'AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole' policy attached to it. The ARN for the lambda seems to be correct under its own permissions.

Comment: Last night I did return the event so that I could see it. It was different between tests.

Comment: Weirdly enough, I was able to access the event object in nodeJS version of the lambda function yesterday with identical set up. But then had problems reading and writing to the Dynamo table :-(

Comment: Response body using Postman with same Body: {
    "errorMessage": "'body'",
    "errorType": "KeyError",
    "stackTrace": [
        "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 12, in lambda_handler\n    jsonEvent = json.loads(event['body'])\n"
    ]
}

Comment: Response body using API GateWay: {
  "tableId": {
    "S": "123123"
  },
  "This is a test": {
    "N": "67"
  }
}

Answer (score 1):

So I believe I solved the issue. I simply un-ticked the 'use lambda proxy integration' box when setting up the post method in API Gateway. Now I'm receiving the body as the event as I wanted. Thank you for your responses anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
def handler(event, context):
  requestObject = ""
  if "requestObject" in event:
      requestObject = event["requestObject"]
  else:
      requestJson = json.loads(event["body"])
      if "requestObject" in requestJson:
          serialNumber = requestJson["requestObject"]
```